# executable wont run via citrix server

Tags: vb.net, citrix

The vb.net code:

Dim fs2 As Object

fs2 = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

gets an error when I try to make an executable file out of this program and run it via citrix server.

The error is, the executable file won't run at all.

When I try to run this locally, there are no errors at all.

Thanks for your help in advance!

Answer (score 0):

1) .Net has system.IO.File/Directory etc, do you really need this unmanaged object ?  2) Are you sure this statement is stopping your whole app ? Does it load if you exclude the statement ?  3) Try it in VBA (eg Excel) or VBS on the Cirtix server to see if any better errors turn up. 4) Check the registry for HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Scripting.FileSystemObject on the server - this is where it appears on a client.